# Detecting the element under object being dragged

Tags: javascript

I have an absolutely positioned element as the last child of the `<body>`. It is being dragged. I have the x, y position of this element and want to find out which element is visually underneath it.

I have heard about the `document.getElementFromPoint(x, y)` method. But obviously that would just return the element that is being dragged as that is the element in the top of the z-index stack. Also because this element's only parent is `<body>` this make things more difficult.

Any thoughts?

(PS. I need a pure javascript solution).

Comment: `dragenter` and `dragover` are fired on elements if an element is dragged over them. You can probably use these. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing, the state of drag and drop isn't so hot. Jquery's implementation only works well in some situations (not the one I've been developing), and the dragenter/dragover spec in HTML5 is a mess.

If you can use jQuery UI's solution, please do so. Otherwise, you'll have to maintain a list of objects that qualify as draggable targets, and cycle through checking each of them as you drag your object around (I have a rather complicated drag and drop app, its what we're doing, if there is another viable solution I'd love to hear it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you would like to achieve but take a look at jQuery UI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/), most importantly the later which makes it easy to manipulate the behaviour of elements which support other elements being dropped on them or dragged over them.

Comment: Oh, I just read the PS, sorry if by pure JS you meant no jQuery.